# How to write "correct" member function for enums?

Tags: python, enums

See this code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from enum import Enum

class AType(Enum):
    A = 1
    B = 2

    def as_key(self):
        if self.name == AType.A:
            return 'key for As'
        else:
            return 'some other key'

print(AType.A.as_key())
print(AType.B.as_key())
```

Coming from the java world; I would have expected it to print

```
key for As
some other key
```

but I get:

```
some other key
some other key
```

Probably super-simply, but what is the correct way to write such a member function that gives me a result depending on the "enum constant" I invoke the method on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, to get it out of the way: `self.name` is already key, so

```
def as_key(self):
    return self.name
```

But I assume this is not what you wanted - that function was probably just a basic example, and you want to write more complex functions that do different things based on the enum.

`Enum` values are singletonish - `AType.A` will always return the exact same object(as opposed to the string `"A"`, which may create a new object each time - though as an optimization the literal will always return the same object if it's still in memory).

Also, inside the method, `self` is the actual enum object - `AType.A` or `AType.B`.

So - just compare `self` to the enum values:

```
def as_key(self):
    if self is AType.A:
        return 'A'
    elif self is AType.B:
        return 'B'
    else:
        assert False, 'Unknown AType %s' % (self,)
```

BTW: the `is` operator in Python is equivalent to `==` in Java - it checks for exact object identity(that it's the same object in the same place in memory). Python's `==` operator is equivalent to Java's `equals()` method - it can be customized to compare the values of the objects.

Comment: Accepting your answer made me hit 40000 rep. Meaning: you won in the upvote lottery ;-)